# Como capturar áudio do microfone usando API de áudio do HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html5, html5-audio

Como faço para capturar o áudio do microfone usando a API de áudio do HTML5 e reproduzi-lo ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Observação: há um bug no Google Chrome porque a transmissão de apenas "audio" não funciona: [tópico](http://crbug.com/112367). O elemento `<audio>` também não funcionaria no Opera.   [extraído](http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

Comment: obrigado pelas dicas. Com mta insistência e necessidade, vasculhei a internet quase toda e consegui encontrar o que queria. No Link abaixo tem vários exemplos ótimos e um que foi bem adequado para minha necessidade. Está aqui o link: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-PHP Valeu, abraços a todos. Fiquem com Deus!

Answer (score 3):

Eis um pequeno trecho código que realiza isso (testado com sucesso no Chrome 33 e no Firefox 28):

```
var audioContext, microphoneStream;

function getUserMedia_Success(mediaStream) {
    microphoneStream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(mediaStream);
    //Conecta o microfone à saída
    microphoneStream.connect(audioContext.destination);
    return true;
}

function getUserMedia_Error(error) {
    alert("Erro ao obter acesso ao microfone: " + error);
    return true;
}

//Valida a capacidade do browser de capturar mídia
if (!navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.msGetUserMedia);
}
if (!navigator.getUserMedia) {
    alert("Aparentemente seu browser não possui a API necessária para capturar mídia :(");
    return;
}

//Tenta criar o contexto de áudio para capturar e reproduzir o áudio
audioContext = (window.AudioContext ? new AudioContext() : (window.webkitAudioContext ? new webkitAudioContext() : null));
if (!audioContext) {
    alert("Aparentemente seu browser não possui a API necessária para trabalhar com áudio! :(");
} else {
    //Tenta obter acesso ao microfone
    navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, getUserMedia_Success, getUserMedia_Error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode dar uma olhada no [HTML Media Capture](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/) e sua [API](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-capture-api/).

Laboratórios Ericsson já conseguido isso, veja: [aqui](https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-audio-capture-web-browsers) (Nota: Observe que o elemento do dispositivo e as APIs não estejam disponíveis em qualquer navegador, no entanto, e as APIs podem mudar antes que isso aconteça.) Mas ele lhe dá uma idéia sobre como é feito .

Eu estou trabalhando atualmente em algo como isso mesmo, veja: [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220672/implementing-webbased-real-time-video-chat-using-html5-websockets).

> Fonte:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238672/2191161