# Como fazer captura de áudio com HTML5 e Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, html5-audio

Estou fazendo pesquisas sobre gravação de áudio com HTML5, mas nenhum dos tutoriais que encontrei funcionaram, muitos deles utilizam o getUsermedia(), mas me parece que está deprecated, então, alguém poderia me apresentar um exemplo prático que realmente funcione para captura de áudio com o microfone do pc com HTML5 e Javascript.

Encontrei esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11640/como-capturar-%C3%A1udio-do-microfone-usando-api-de-%C3%A1udio-do-html5) do Leandro Costa, mas não consegui implementar o código da resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Em mídia nem sempre é fácil fazer uma solução que funcione em todos os navegadores. Além disso, alguns casos pode ser necessário ativar flags específicas no Chrome por exemplo. A função que você menciona é a API mais difundida.

Uma fonte de conceitos bacana podes pegar nesse post do [Eric Bidelman](http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) ([versão original](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)).

Para começar, um live demo bem interessante é esse aqui: http://audior.ec/recordmp3js/

O autor tem um blog com mais informações sobre [Gravação de áudio via web](http://audior.ec/blog/recording-mp3-using-only-html5-and-javascript-recordmp3-js/).
A W3C tem uma especificação em andamento, mas ainda está em [draft](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/).

Finalmente, dependendo da sua necessidade, o WebRTC pode ser a melhor alternativa: https://webrtc.org/. Há bons exemplos no site do projeto como a [captura de áudio por microfone](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/audio/).